# Problem with adding class to every children node

Tags: jquery

I have problem with adding class to every list element. This is example html:

```
<ul id="main_list">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2<li>
<ul>
```

And my jquery code which i don't understand why it don't work like i expect:

```
   $(function(){
        $('#main_list').children().each(function(){
            $(this).addClass(function(){
                return $(this).index()})
            })
          })
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do.. add each element's index as a class? If so thats what an id is for.

Comment: I want every li's elements to have class equal to it place in elements set.

Comment: Again you should be adding an id with this not a class. And why bother to do that if you can get the reference through `$(this).index()` off of any event?

Comment: Why add a unique numbered class to every li tag?  What possible use is this?  Do you also realize that a valid class name can't begin with a digit character: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: @locrizak: No reason to use `id` values for that. What if he has two lists on the page, for instance?

Comment: I am trying to build a little complicated for me tree, and for now i see need to giving unique class to every element. Ids are occupated fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the jQuery object on which you're calling `addClass` has only one item in it (you're creating that jQuery object via `$(this)`). Try this:

```
$("#main_list > li").addClass(function() {
    return $(this).index();
});
```

...if you're really trying to assign classes like `0`, `1`, etc. I think I'd probably put something in front of those numbers, though; I can't immediately find it in the spec, but I don't *think* class names can start with digits. So:

```
$("#main_list > li").addClass(function() {
    return 'n' + $(this).index();
});
```

...for `n0`, `n1`, etc.

Comment: Valid class names can't start with a digit.

Comment: I don't care of is class name is vali or not. I just need them working. They will working good with class name as number?

Comment: @jfriend00: I was thinking that too, but then didn't comment because I couldn't immediately find it in the spec. Can you?

Comment: @Cris: I would recommend putting a letter in front of them (updated the answer).

Comment: I don't know this yet, so i ask: if i add letter in front of number, can i cut this lettr latter to get only number?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - It's here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner.  A class is an identifier which in the grammer is `-?{nmstart}{nmchar}*` where nmstart is `[_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}`.   Numbers are then allowed after a non-dash character.

Comment: @Cris, see my answer below.  I think maybe you want to put a sequence number as data on the object (not in a class name) that you can access at any time later.  This would make more sense than trying to parse a number out of a class name when you have no other use for the class name.

Comment: So if You saying that i belive. I need to read this doct and try to understand.

Comment: @Cris, just see my answer below.  No need to read the long spec doc - that was for T.J. who wanted to see the actual grammer for a class name.

Comment: @Cris: Yes, you can easily remove it via `cls = cls.substring(1)` if `cls` is the class name. But if you're not using these classes in your stylesheets, you may want to go with `data` instead as jfriend points out.

Answer (score 2):

To make valid class names (which can't start with a digit):

```
$("#main_list li").addClass(function() {
    return("myItem" + $(this).index());
});
```

But, it sounds to me like you might rather be setting an id:

```
$("#main_list li").attr("id" function() {
    return("myItem" + $(this).index());
});
```

Looking at Cris' (the original poster) comments to other answers, it sounds like what you want to do is to be able to extract the ordered position from the object at some later date.  It might be easier to just put a data attribute on the object that represents it's order like this:

```
// put an attribute on each object that represents it's index so that's easier to get later
$("#main_list li").each(function(index){
    $(this).data("pos", index);
});
```

Then later, you can access that data value with this:

```
item.data("pos");
```

This seems a lot cleaner to me than parsing a number out of class name that you have no other use for.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RDvw2/.

Comment: It give me some new light of waht can i do by jquery. Maybe i find use for this. I need to see again my code and that what i expect it to do. Thank You.

Comment: FYI, adding your own attributes to an object doesn't require jQuery (it's easy to do in plain javascript), but jQuery makes it pretty simple.

Comment: I prefer jquery more than js because i have no skills yet in js and i need do something very quick.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to add that this feature isn't unique to jQuery.

Comment: For example every first element in collection will has this same position if i use `.each(function(index){
    $(this).data("pos", index);`

Comment: @Cris - were you asking a question?  If so, I don't follow what you're asking.

Comment: Now i am not asking, i just give assertion.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to number the li's based on their position in the ul?

```
function addClasses( )
{
    $( '#main_list' ).children( ).each( function( index )
    {
        $( this ).addClass( 'myClass' + index );
    } );
}
```

edit: as jfriend00 pointed out, class name can not start with a digit.

Comment: Yes, i want to number the lis basing on their positions in ul.